# Is having to many nested elements bad?

Tags: html, css

```
<!-- beginning of main-container  -->
<div class="main-container">
  <main>
    <section>
      <h3>Featured Stories</h3>
      <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="bird-story.jpg" alt="A red-flanked bluetail roosting on the grounds of Library" title="A red-flanked bluetail roosting on the grounds of Library" /></a>
        <footer>
          <a href="#"><h4>Rare bird attracts crowds</h4></a>
          <figcaption>A red&dash;flanked bluetail roosting on the grounds of Library is popular with birders&period;</figcaption>
        </footer>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
<!-- end of main-header -->
```

I read that HTML is supposed to be semantic meaning that you're supposed to describe the meaning of your content instead of how it looks. Do you guys think I overdo it? Sometimes it confuses me when I try to style it.

Comment: Not really. Just don't add unnecessary elements and keep structure in your code.

Comment: Ehm... is your code meant to be an example of too many nested elements?

Comment: Once I've seen 12 nested tables and I cried. Your markup is absolutely reasonable.

Comment: @MrLister yes of what i though was to many nested elements

Comment: @fcalderan ok thank you for the help!

Comment: @Tygo ok ill do that thank you for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having too many nested elements are not bad. The bad is to have too many unnecessary element. Having unnecessary elements will grow your DOM and will slow the DOM manipulation processes if performed.

In your html,

- You can get rid of your **section** tag, if there is only 1 section
  within **main**.
- Wrapping of **h4** within **a** is an invalid html w.r.t semantics
  (block level element within inline-block element). Should have used
  it the other way(**a** inside **h4**)
- **footer** tag can also be omitted. But again, it will depend on how
  much focus you want to have to the **figcaption** w.r.t seo.

There is absolutely no such rule, it's all about have a perspective while writing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Html is all to do with structure from what i learned. Maybe try spacing out your html to make it easier to read (trust me it will save time in the long run, when looking for small mistakes) Try using some sort of a text editor to get the idea of clean html into your head always helps. Also not too sure why you have a footer tag embedded, the tag is usually used for copyright stuffs etc. If your looking to decrease the size of the text just use css. Rule of thumb css appearance html structure.

Just put an id on what text you want to make smaller and change the font size in your css later. Saves you using the unnecessary footer tag

```
<!-- beginning of main-container  -->
<div class="main-container">
  <main>
    <section>

      <h3>Featured Stories</h3>

      <figure>

        <a href="#"><img src="bird-story.jpg" alt="A red-flanked bluetail roosting on the grounds of Library" title="A red-flanked bluetail roosting on the grounds of Library" /></a>
        <a href="#"><h4>Rare bird attracts crowds</h4></a>
        <figcaption id = "Smaller text" >A red&dash;flanked bluetail roosting on the grounds of Library is popular with birders&period;</figcaption>

      </figure>

    </section>

  </main>

</div>
<!-- end of main-header -->
```

Comment: ok i will download atom. I will remove the footer element. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no limit for tag nesting levels, it is just a matter of good practices. Maintaining a code with many levels may find a hard thing to keep doing along the time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. Sometimes it's better to add one more div that can save several lines of code. If you start the project from the beginning, go with the line you started, when you continue, for example a bootstrap project, you should write the way you received.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of HTML is to display data in a semantic and meaningful way. Nesting is a way to describe hierarchy between elements: an article contains a heading and a few paragraphs; a table contains rows and rows contain cells; a list contains items.

You should design your HTML in a way that represents the relations of the *data* and sections of your site, and avoid adding markup that is primarily for styling purposes. As long as each nested item has a meaningful reason to be nested then you are free to nest as much as you like. Ask yourself whether it makes sense for the parent tag to contain the child tag or whether they should instead be siblings.